# 2D array loses its format when received as a function return

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, format

I can not figure out why this happens.

```
    function modified_my_2d_array() {
    my_2d_array = array(
        0 => array(
            'Unique Identifier' => '1',
            'Other Column' => 'Random text',
        ),
        1 => array(
            'Unique Identifier' => '10',
            'Other Column' => 'Random text',
        ),
        2 => array(
            'Unique Identifier' => '300',
            'Other Column' => 'Random text',
        ),
        3 => array(
            'Unique Identifier' => '30',
            'Other Column' => 'Random text',
        ),
    );
    foreach ($my_2d_array as &$row) {
        if (in_array($row['Unique Identifier'], $unique_identifiers_needed)) {
            $row['STO_UID'] = $row['Unique Identifier'];
        }
        else {
            $row['STO_UID'] = str_pad($row['Unique Identifier'], 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        }
    }

    // Here the "STO_UID" column is formated as XXX. Ex: 001, 010, 300, 030.
    return $my_2d_array;
}

function calling_function() {
    $my_array = modified_my_2d_array();
    // Here the "STO_UID" column is not formated as XXX anymore. Ex: 1, 10, 300, 30.
}
```

Im trying to always have the STO_UID in a XXX format but, while that format is being remembered whitin the function where the array is being modified, its format is lost when assigned to a variable as a return array of a function... Any ideas ?

Comment: Where does `$my_2d_array` come from in the first function? It appears to be undefined. Am I missing something, or is something missing?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, i didnt write the whole function: this is more like a mock up function of the problem i have... i will update the question with an array fill-up

Comment: I figured that was the case. I just thought it might matter if it's passed as an argument, defined within the function, global, etc.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. It stays formatted for me. Could you maybe show a working (or, I guess non-working) example in https://3v4l.org/ or another similar online shell?

Comment: There is no need for the in_array conditional and unless `$unique_identifiers_needed` is an array, which you don't tell us, the funciton call is wrong: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php. I couldn't reproduce the error too.